# Sqlite and java.sql library - Checking Indices Created For a Sqlite Table

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, indexing, schema

How can I see/inspect a list of indices existing at a point in time for a specific table? I'm using SQLite and am creating the table and its indices in my Java code. Is there a way for me to get the list of indices I created on the table in Java?

Comment: You can get the `DatabaseMetaData` from the connection, and that can give you a way to get the indexes of a table.

Comment: Which method in DatabaseMetaData does the job?

Comment: This http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/GetIndexInfo.htm may help you.

Comment: If that helped, I have added my comment as an answer, accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `DatabaseMetaData` from the connection, and that can give you a way to get the indexes of a table.

Follow [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/GetIndexInfo.htm) tutorial for the reference.